# One-to-many relationship in Laravel: Placing many pizzas in one order

Tags: laravel-4

By the way, I am a newbie in programming and I am currently trying to study Laravel..

So basically, I am creating an ordering system for customized pizza and I am integrating a somehow cart-like function..

[Index page for Orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVQOm.png)

What I want to do is that every time I click "Add Pizza" it will redirect to the pizza creation page and then stores it so a specific order_id. For a single order_id, I can put as many pizzas as I want until the user decides to submit the order..

[This is what I would like to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMEfP.png)

But everytime I create a pizza.. It always stores it to another order_id..

Here's a portion of my code:

This is the index page where all pizzas within the order is displayed..

```
public function index()
    {
        //create new object orders
        $orders = new Order;//where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();


        return View::make('order.index')
            ->with('orders', $orders);
    }
```

Code to store the pizza in the order..

```
public function store()
    {
        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
        $order= new Order;
        $order->user()->associate($user);
        $order->toAddress = 'Caimito St., Balite Drive, Brgy. Santiago';
        $order->amount = 125.00;
        $order->save();

        $pizza = new Pizza;

        $pizza->pizza_name='Jets Pizza';
        $pizza->amount=0;
        $quantity = Input::get('quantity');
        $pizza->quantity = $quantity;
        $pizza->save();



        $base = Input::get('base');
            $pizza->ingredients()->attach($base);

        $cheese = Input::get('cheese');
            $pizza->ingredients()->attach($cheese);

        $meats = Input::get('meat');

        if(sizeof($meats) != 0) {
            foreach ($meats as $meat) {
            $pizza->ingredients()->attach($meat);

            }   
        }


        $chilis = Input::get('chili');

        if(sizeof($chilis) != 0) {
            foreach ($chilis as $chill) {
            $pizza->ingredients()->attach($chill);
            }   
        }


        $toppings = Input::get('toppings');

        if(sizeof($toppings) != 0){
            foreach ($toppings as $topping) {
            $pizza->ingredients()->attach($topping);
            }
        }

        $amount = 0;

        foreach($pizza->ingredients as $ingr){
            $amount = $amount + $ingr->price;
        }


        $total_amount;

        $pizza->amount = $amount;


        $pizza->save();

        $order->pizzas()->attach($pizza);
        // $order->pizzas->quantity = 5;
        $order->save();

        return Redirect::to('/order/index');

    }
```

Here is the definition for my relationships in my models:

```
public function pizzas(){
        // hasMany('ngalan sa model padulngan', 'ngalan sa junction table', 'name id sa gi-gikanan', 'name sa id sa padulngan nga junction table')
        return $this->belongsToMany('Pizza','order_details','order_id','pizza_id');
    }

public function orders(){
        // belongsToMany('ngalan sa model', 'ngalan sa junction table' , 'name sa id sa padulngan nga junction table',  'name id sa gi-gikanan')
        return $this->belongsToMany('Order','order_details', 'pizza_id' , 'order_id');
    }
```

Comment: show pizzas function in order model

Comment: hi @Janko, i edited my post to show the relationships in my models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As fas as I understand, your models should be: Order hasMany Pizza and Pizza belongsTo order.

Order model

```
public function pizzas(){
    return $this->hasMany('Pizza');
}
```

Pizza model

```
public function order(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Order');
}
```

In your store function you create a single order and a pizza. When you create the pizza, you can do $pizza->order_id = $order->id (you must first create the order). Then you can continue attaching ingredients to your pizza. I believe a pizza can't belong to many orders. How would that be?

Comment: thank you @Eduardo Pacios.. yes.. yes. i also thought about that.. i have another code which has relationships like that.. my problem is having as many pizzas as i want in a single order_id.. do i put the $order = new Order; in the store function?

Comment: lets say you create an order with id 1. You create 7 pizzas, all of them with order_id = 1. Then you write $order->pizzas you will get those 7 pizzas. That answers the question?

Comment: yes, i understand that. but my problem is that everytime i run the store() function in my OrderController.. it create another order with a diff. id.. so everytime i customize a pizza.. it stores it individually to the new order_id...  i  believe the problem is in my routing.. shall I create the pizza within the OrderController or in my PizzaController?